# How can I change my Stack Overflow password?

Tags: stack, overflow, change-password

I want to change my Stack Overflow password, but I don't know how to do it. Is there a kind soul who wants to tell me the way?

I can't find the option in my Stack Overflow dashboard.

Thank you!

Comment: Questions about using [so] belong on [meta].

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285427/56778

Answer (score 1):

Under your dashboard, settings, access, your logins

Comment: Firstly, the question belongs on a different site so you shouldn't have even answered it. But if you do, please note that your answer is not easy to understand and you would certainly like to support it with an image of how this action should be performed.